# Showing device name from Java in XML (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth

I am looking for a way to show the android device name (fetched automatically from the phone) in a TextView. I have read answers but since I don't fully understand them yet since I'm new to this I'm hoping you can help me out.

My way of doing this is getting the device name from the Bluetooth Adapter. I have added the following to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

I've then added the following to MainActivity.java. I will add the if null value once I get this working.

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

How do I get the String deviceName to my TextView in activity_main.xml?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is how my TextVew looks in activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

This is what the MainActivty.java looks like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(deviceName);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: Your question belongs to lesson one of Android programming.

Comment: @greenapps What do you mean by this? I'm currently on the Udacity Beginners Course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to add an ID or anything to my TextView? and what do I write in the "android:text="" ? I am still not sure HOW the deviceName will popup in the XML file

When ever you want deal with any `View` in runtime, you should give a `Id` to so that you can get the `View` by using `findViewById(int)` as shown below code

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

once you get that View you can manipulate the `View`.

In your case you need to set the text of the `TextView` to your bluetooth name.
so you can use `setText()` method of `TextView`

```
tv.setText("I'm Jay");
```

**With that Background**

Place a `TextView` inside your activity's xml layout file.

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

and in Java code 
inside activity's java code within `onCreate()` place this code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
tv.setText(deviceName);
..
..
}
```

#### Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you not only for writing the code, but also learning me about it. However, the app keeps crashing now when I'm debugging it on my phone. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you should post error in order to help you, you can find it in logcat

Comment: you must set a contentview for the activity before you reference any view

Comment: Yes, after setting the contentview everything works perfectly, thank you so much Jayanth.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the following:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText("Device name: " + deviceName);
```

The setText() method sets the String you provide to the TextView. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Where do I put this line? in the .java file? And what will be the string name? I've just started learning, sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: @5emtio4yra yes right below the code you have written in the question.

Comment: Do I need to add an ID or anything to my TextView? and what do I write in the "android:text="" ? I am still not sure HOW the deviceName will popup in the XML file...

Comment: Nothing will pop up in an xml file. Your text becomes visible in the textview.

Comment: How is that possible when I have three textvews and I haven't declared which one?

Comment: You did with R.id.myTextView.

Comment: @5emtio4yra you need to declare id in xml for all the three textviews using android:id="@+id/id". ID needs to be unique for all the textviews

Answer (score 0):

First find your textView and after set the value.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
textView.setText(deviceName);
```